# How do I update changes in a datagridview back to the database?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I use a datatable as source for the datagridview. How do I save changes made in the datagridview back to the database?

Comment: How do you populate the datatable? Are you using asp.net or windows forms?

Comment: i use windows forms. I populate the datatable with an adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to call the Update method of the adapter when you want to save the changes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update%28v=VS.100%29.aspx