# How to refresh/update the datagridview in the case of multiuser?

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a prob. I created a windows form to save payment details of employees in a company and there is a "data grid view" in my form and a combo box inside it , if i make "paid" (two values inside the grid 1.Paid 2. Pending ) for a person his name will not show again and it is working correctly... but my problem in the case of multi-user , if user-A make paid for some person it will remove from his grid but not from the second user (say user-B) means paid person is showing to the User-B 's datagridview .. Is there any solution ? pls Help me

Comment: Your problem is a collaboration problem. There is have some of variant solutions but it still depends on current architect your software. You should build a broadcast event to all of clients which connecting to your system. You need a transaction manager to broadcast or notify event to all of clients.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to bind the DataGridView to DataBase. This will do the update automatically, that is to mean two things:

1. Any changes made
    by the user in the DataGridView will automically be made to the
    DataBase by calling the Update function of the OleDbDatAdapter with
    the DataTable as the argument to accomplish dAdapter.Update(dTable);
2. When the content of Datasource(DataBase) is changed, the simplest
    way to update the changes in DataGridView is to clear its DataSource and then rebound with the DataSource.

Coding like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;    //clear its DataSource
        dataGridView1.DataSource = oTable;   //rebound with the DataSource
    }
```

good [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx), [How do I update changes in a datagridview back to the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793899/how-do-i-update-changes-in-a-datagridview-back-to-the-database)